# Compiling PHP with --enable-embedded-mysqli and --with-mysqli

Tags: php, bash, mysqli, compilation

Is there some difference between the two? I compiled my PHP 5.5.8 with the following:

```shell
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-pdo-mysql --with-gd --enable-embedded-mysqli --enable-zip --enable-mysqlnd --enable-cgi ...
```

and later, in the installed PHP; I was receiving:

> call to undefined function **`mysqli_connect`**

On looking at the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php); I notice that the command is actually

```
--with-mysqli
```

But I was presented with the `--enable-embedded-mysqli` option on tab completion by bash and thus, never thought to look further. What does the `--enable-embedded-mysqli` command do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--enable-embedded-mysqli seem to activate [MySQL Embedded](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/libmysqld.html) support, but isn't very well documented.

Comment: I was compiling PHP; not MySQL. The linked page mentions `--with-embedded-privilege-control`

Comment: I know, what I say: it's seem to activate an embedded mysql server into php. The link is just the subjacent library in C.