# Compiling PHP with MySQLi embedded on Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, compilation, embedded-database

I am trying to determine whether or not it is possible to use a MySQL embedded in PHP in a windows 7 enviroment.  [The PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php) indicates that the MySQLi extension has the ability to start and stop an embedded MySQL server.

However the distributed builds for windows by PHP.net do not seem to have that option enabled.  My internet searches have shown me this question : [Compiling PHP with --enable-embedded-mysqli and --with-mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241294/compiling-php-with-enable-embedded-mysqli-and-with-mysqli) which seems to indicate that if I compile PHP I can enable the embedded MySQL server commands.

While I can successfully build a vanilla PHP I seem to be unable to get `buildconf` to provide `configure` with the `--enable-embedded-mysqli` option.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have since determined that `buildconf` uses `config.w32` files to find its options (I believe).

For the MySLQi extension the `config.m4` file (used for building on a Unix based system) defines the `--enable-embedded-mysqli` option which allows you to compile PHP with the MySLQ embedded server, however the windows version of the file `config.w32` does not define this option.  Seems like my alternatives are to either learn more about building extensions in general and "fix" the issue or understand that PHP on Windows simply doesn't support MySQL embedded . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so after extensive research and testing I have found a solution

Compiling PHP on windows relies on config.w32 files to provide configure and the make file the necessary instructions to configure and then compile PHP.  The Unix variant is the config.m4 file.

The problem is the Windows varient doesn't have the logic to activate the embedded server.

Original code (just the part of interest)

```
if (CHECK_LIB("libmysql.lib", "mysqli", PHP_MYSQLI) &&
    CHECK_HEADER_ADD_INCLUDE("mysql.h", "CFLAGS_MYSQLI", PHP_MYSQLI + 
                                        "\\include;" + PHP_PHP_BUILD +
                                        "\\include\\mysql;" + PHP_MYSQLI)) {
    EXTENSION("mysqli", mysqli_source);
    AC_DEFINE('HAVE_MYSQLILIB', 1, 'Have MySQLi library');
    MESSAGE("\tlibmysql build");
    PHP_INSTALL_HEADERS("ext/mysqli", "php_mysqli_structs.h");
} else {
    WARNING("mysqli not enabled; libraries and headers not found");
    PHP_MYSQLI = "no"
}
```

You need to modify this code to allow for the server embedded.

```
if (PHP_EMBEDDED_MYSQLI != "no") {
    if (CHECK_LIB("libmysqld.lib", "mysqli", PHP_MYSQLI) &&
        CHECK_HEADER_ADD_INCLUDE("mysql.h", "CFLAGS_MYSQLI", PHP_MYSQLI + 
                                        "\\include;" + PHP_PHP_BUILD +
                                        "\\include\\mysql;" + PHP_MYSQLI)) {
        EXTENSION("mysqli", mysqli_source);
        AC_DEFINE('HAVE_MYSQLILIB', 1, 'Have MySQLi library');
        MESSAGE("\tlibmysql build");
        AC_DEFINE('HAVE_EMBEDDED_MYSQLI', 1, 'Embedded MySQL support enabled');
        MESSAGE("\tEmbedded MySQL build");
        PHP_INSTALL_HEADERS("ext/mysqli", "php_mysqli_structs.h");
    } else {
        WARNING("mysqli not enabled; libraries and headers not found");
        PHP_MYSQLI = "no"
    }
} else {
    if (CHECK_LIB("libmysql.lib", "mysqli", PHP_MYSQLI) &&
        CHECK_HEADER_ADD_INCLUDE("mysql.h", "CFLAGS_MYSQLI", PHP_MYSQLI + 
                                        "\\include;" + PHP_PHP_BUILD +
                                        "\\include\\mysql;" + PHP_MYSQLI)) {
        EXTENSION("mysqli", mysqli_source);
        AC_DEFINE('HAVE_MYSQLILIB', 1, 'Have MySQLi library');
        MESSAGE("\tlibmysql build");
        PHP_INSTALL_HEADERS("ext/mysqli", "php_mysqli_structs.h");
    } else {
        WARNING("mysqli not enabled; libraries and headers not found");
        PHP_MYSQLI = "no"
    } 
}
```

You also need to add the following line at the top of the file right below the ARG_WITH() line.

```
ARG_ENABLE("embedded-mysqli", "Enable the embedded mysqli server", "no");
```

Running `buildconf` will now produce a configure file with the option to embed mysqli and configure.

```
configure --with-extra-includes=[path-to-mysql-dir\include] --with-extra-libs=[path-to-mysql-dir\lib] --without-mysqlnd --with-mysqli=shared,libmysqldclient --enable-embedded-mysqli [other options here]
```

You can now run `nmake` and `nmake snap` to compile PHP :)

You will need to copy libmysqld.dll into C:\mysql\php (or wherever you placed php).  You enable php via php.ini like normal.

The reason for building PHP as a shared module instead of a static module is `nmake snap` fails because it starts PHP in order to package the php distro, if MySQLi was build statically it will now look for its mysql dependencies at start-up and fail silently (no errors given) when it doesn't find them.

Place the mysql config file (my.ini) one directory above php.exe  This will ensure that you can specify custom directories to link PHP to your mysql build.  Use the group [embedded], not [mysqld] to pass along the configurations.

The only thing that would make this solution work even better would to if I were capable of finding a way to place the my.ini file in the same directory as PHP.  I shall try building MySQL from source to set this variable at compile time.